# To filter sales based on max date value minus 6 months

Tags: date, sas

I'm trying to filter the data based on the date filter. The date column in my table is in date9. format(30JUN2017).

I want to filter the date column by subtracting 6 months from the existing date, which will be 31DEC2017.

e.g: date<31DEC2017

Can anyhow suggest on how to do this, I have tried using intx function and other options as well.

Thanks for your help.

Best Regards,
AJ

Comment: You can subtract one date from another to directly get the number of days between them, and compare this 180 days (approximately six months). Use '31dec2017'd if you want to embed a literal date in your code. What have you tried (precisely), what results did you get, and why did you consider the results wrong/unsatisfactory?

Comment: `intnx` is the standard function to use here.  What didn't work when you tried using that? p.s. 6 months back from 30JUN2017 is 31DEC2016, not 2017

Answer (score 0):

When manipulating dates in SAS using their formatted values you should enclose them in `""d`, i.e. in your example it should be `where date<"31DEC2017"d`. If your date is stored in date9 format as a string, you can make it into a date like so: `where input(date,date9.)<"31DEC2017"d`

Now your question seems to differ slightly from its title. According to the latter, you want to filter on max_date - 6 months, whatever that max date might be in your dataset. This could be done so:

```
proc sql;
  select *
  from t
  where intnx('month',date,6)<(select max(date) from t)
  ;
quit;
```

If however, for some strange reason, by "max date" you mean the current date, the above query simply becomes this:

```
proc sql;
  select *
  from t
  where intnx('month',date,6)<date()
  ;
quit;
```